# YouTube data download with cclive & gcap

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

In a PHP system, my client suggested to download videos AND MAINLY captions from YouTube using the following tools:

- [cclive](http://cclive.sourceforge.net/)
- [gcap](https://code.google.com/p/gcap/)

As I have never heard of these before, my question is does anyone have any experience with them? Both projects seem to be inactive for like one year or so... Do they still work?

Is it possible to download captions for any YT video with them? I have stumbled upon some YT API info that the captions are not available for unauthorized users (i.e. you can only get your own captions if you are authorized with the API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caption tracks can only be accessed via the Data API by the authorized owner of a given video.

The official YouTube Players can access caption data, but they use a different mechanism for accessing that data which is not part of a public API.

Comment: Yea, thought & read so, as I said. However - how comes these tools claim to do it then?

Comment: That would be an ideal question to pose to the authors of those tools. I can only tell you that it's not possible to do the things you mention using any supported API, and that you should be sure to follow the YouTube API Terms of Service.

Comment: Yea, my POV too. Exactly what I told the client - if the TOS state something then we should stick to it. Even if there is a workaround... We don't want our server to get blacklisted or what...